# - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions was not triggered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I used

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

to get the launchOptions.

But it was not triggered, even if I added the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Welcome any comment

Comment: How did you set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure the File's Owner `delegate` outlet is connected to your App delegate class in the main nib file, unless you want to set it programmatically:

[image]

Comment: I have linked file's owner delegate to app delegate

Answer (score 1):

Which iOS version did you try? This works in iOS 3.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I recall some odd behavior (this may or may not be true, but something to try) that if you ALSO implement the old method:

```
- (BOOL)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then it will call that instead.  Can you confirm you don't have that method?